# How to convert a string of pixels into an image with python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am having a string of pixels of a B/W image in this manner:-

```
48 34 21 18 16 21 26 36 40...44 53 57 64 82 95 9
```

of string length 547, and I want these pixels to be converted into an image of `48*48` pixel B/W image.

**Is there any python library or PyTorch function to make it possible?**

Link to the [Notebook](https://jovian.ml/manishshah120/finalproject287imageclassifier)

Comment: Is there any inherent structure to the "string of pixels"?

Comment: No @MateenUlhaq

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, then. Any arbitrary function matches your description. P.S. For the curious, 547 is prime and `sqrt(547) = 23.4`.

Comment: If you have a 48x48 image, you will need nearly 2,500 values which cannot fit in a 547 byte string.

Comment: This is the Notebook I am Working on [Notebook](https://jovian.ml/manishshah120/finalproject287imageclassifier)<br>
Pardon me if I am wrong in providing some information in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`PIL.Image.frombuffer()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=frombuffer#PIL.Image.frombuffer) function for example.

```
from PIL import Image

pixels = '126 126 129 120 110 168 174 172 173 174 170 157 134 97 78 75 118 119 97 117 142 86 58 71 124 161 162 134 100 119 124 118 153 135 143 180 180 172 153 128 98 67 60 75 85 89 85 98 123 126 131 119 119 172 180 171 155 127 100 82 77 72 54 97 184 151 157 176 125 74 71 114 173 171 136 109 116 118 118 150 152 150 178 191 188 187 180 169 152 127 86 60 74 91 92 95 119 131 127 115 113 153 130 94 71 62 65 69 83 95 79 137 181 174 196 148 88 75 103 149 135 107 100 105 104 112 140 162 178 191 187 181 171 166 159 156 159 155 144 97 54 69 83 91 112 116 100 85 74 73 59 58 67 75 74 80 104 110 96 153 180 182 151 100 103 139 167 172 152 141 135 135 141 163 182 191 191 183 179 169 144 127 132 147 156 154 152 143 92 52 56 78 97 86 69 60 51 48 55 65 74 74 71 92 121 122 115 155 177 166 151 158 181 200 201 208 207 198 187 181 182 189 187 187 179 170 154 119 91 86 101 124 139 154 153 153 132 73 51 60 63 52 48 45 46 54 65 78 79 86 96 131 163 146 133 162 179 193 202 211 205 208 216 218 209 204 191 183 184 183 176 170 153 127 96 98 127 148 148 142 134 140 150 154 149 102 49 53 57 58 65 68 70 75 75 74 90 121 151 176 176 148 156 170 193 209 215 211 203 213 219 212 206 201 183 174 173 166 162 135 101 86 99 147 176 175 166 164 157 146 148 155 154 128 55 53 54 54 77 92 89 68 58 61 69 94 143 171 155 150 161 163 185 197 203 202 207 213 212 209 202 195 176 163 157 153 125 83 86 118 160 179 172 165 161 161 166 164 155 155 153 138 74 54 40 70 110 122 106 92 112 123 116 108 96 94 118 146 155 159 166 174 180 187 198 213 216 205 196 192 178 155 139 117 88 96 131 163 159 142 130 126 123 123 132 139 147 156 158 145 75 59 60 117 163 157 138 157 176 179 186 189 167 121 98 105 123 149 161 162 165 178 196 213 214 199 188 181 171 147 117 97 104 124 134 127 123 131 135 139 138 137 144 146 139 147 135 106 75 69 98 155 184 180 178 189 187 182 181 190 203 198 165 126 102 109 138 162 171 193 216 225 222 204 191 182 154 130 116 118 137 143 125 108 100 96 96 102 122 129 145 158 142 96 90 127 88 50 125 175 195 191 191 189 178 166 165 172 175 178 177 162 139 116 112 130 158 194 211 216 218 202 189 165 132 129 134 143 129 104 86 98 80 90 128 97 70 90 117 149 161 109 127 151 112 58 145 187 200 198 192 185 174 171 180 162 135 117 120 126 128 128 124 116 124 157 171 166 156 126 107 92 101 127 129 104 93 105 119 137 113 136 145 136 118 107 119 149 162 147 152 152 125 77 142 183 189 176 177 178 174 163 118 109 118 109 95 83 94 101 114 134 125 120 152 153 154 152 156 124 99 103 122 111 112 136 151 156 163 160 160 163 155 143 145 159 163 137 141 147 126 86 119 158 161 184 183 185 163 100 98 167 135 126 89 99 116 104 101 146 144 115 162 197 201 191 189 156 112 94 103 108 112 127 141 150 153 155 156 148 141 149 156 157 165 155 144 146 129 86 112 140 156 191 190 179 144 126 159 179 160 150 148 143 135 127 135 138 137 117 151 199 195 178 177 169 123 105 100 106 115 132 138 143 145 145 143 139 149 156 156 151 141 141 143 143 130 94 131 136 142 181 198 188 177 189 193 185 183 166 152 136 123 121 130 125 132 143 186 207 192 177 177 169 140 119 128 141 142 147 154 159 158 155 158 156 153 146 132 114 122 136 136 134 127 105 136 143 151 167 184 190 198 189 175 168 160 148 138 131 131 144 160 181 176 168 212 206 202 198 185 173 160 150 133 139 148 155 158 164 165 158 146 133 119 113 118 127 130 127 126 125 124 113 176 181 163 183 177 177 184 186 183 172 164 160 160 164 165 174 189 184 171 206 218 212 206 198 187 180 177 171 157 125 113 116 121 127 126 126 126 129 133 136 134 128 121 118 117 115 113 111 175 199 166 177 196 190 188 189 190 190 188 186 184 182 183 189 179 150 171 208 219 209 201 191 181 173 167 152 150 159 157 148 149 154 155 157 153 146 142 140 130 124 117 112 113 108 100 104 175 199 190 163 181 191 187 187 191 191 189 185 179 170 161 155 150 168 168 185 221 204 193 181 168 165 157 137 120 126 158 167 164 168 168 166 160 152 147 144 138 127 118 113 106 103 95 95 173 196 200 206 189 175 168 169 171 167 166 159 154 155 162 176 190 172 147 191 213 202 193 179 162 158 154 137 124 108 123 155 163 167 169 167 164 157 151 144 135 128 120 113 106 99 92 89 164 192 203 215 214 208 206 193 183 175 173 176 179 185 194 196 182 142 148 202 213 204 202 187 173 165 154 151 135 112 102 131 154 157 162 161 158 149 142 137 129 123 117 108 101 95 88 85 156 189 205 211 206 206 206 202 197 198 194 197 201 201 195 178 156 129 171 211 216 214 208 190 179 171 168 149 132 117 102 112 134 152 154 150 150 143 137 131 123 119 112 103 96 91 83 84 148 189 202 204 201 198 199 201 202 201 197 194 192 191 177 159 133 136 189 206 208 210 199 186 180 176 161 129 129 117 106 114 126 144 149 149 145 141 135 130 122 116 108 98 93 90 81 83 149 190 200 199 194 196 199 194 193 192 185 182 180 172 161 141 129 159 188 186 193 194 185 176 173 164 123 93 105 104 117 127 125 132 145 149 142 137 134 129 119 111 103 96 92 87 79 83 159 190 197 198 190 188 188 186 182 180 174 169 165 160 145 126 134 180 187 154 158 186 175 154 151 137 99 84 87 101 124 130 131 131 140 146 143 136 133 126 117 109 99 92 88 85 76 80 171 189 192 187 184 182 182 179 173 169 168 160 156 148 135 124 158 191 196 172 158 169 146 126 123 117 103 102 104 114 128 132 135 133 133 143 144 138 130 122 112 104 96 90 87 84 76 73 175 190 184 180 178 173 171 169 167 162 159 156 152 139 123 131 177 189 192 188 177 167 147 122 111 101 100 110 116 117 131 133 133 135 134 140 144 138 129 117 108 103 97 95 92 85 76 69 179 191 186 178 171 168 164 162 156 151 153 150 144 131 118 151 181 191 198 193 183 175 163 136 112 109 115 118 121 126 136 132 130 132 129 137 144 140 127 116 108 105 101 99 92 86 76 67 160 190 184 173 169 161 156 152 148 144 146 147 141 120 126 172 184 195 203 200 191 184 174 159 142 139 133 129 133 138 135 131 124 124 127 130 141 145 132 119 112 109 106 104 96 88 73 64 110 184 188 176 168 158 145 143 144 147 146 146 136 115 145 176 184 198 199 196 197 190 178 163 159 157 149 145 144 141 134 129 121 119 126 128 138 151 141 124 117 113 110 106 98 88 69 60 89 172 189 178 170 163 149 138 144 152 155 154 128 128 166 178 184 193 197 200 198 192 182 170 163 168 162 156 147 140 136 132 121 115 118 124 130 155 152 132 126 118 110 106 98 86 66 56 60 157 186 180 173 167 153 142 155 167 166 156 125 151 174 178 178 185 193 189 191 188 175 168 167 162 144 130 126 122 122 124 118 112 117 121 124 155 163 137 129 118 110 107 104 86 63 57 41 140 184 178 178 170 159 154 172 183 181 158 134 161 170 176 176 184 184 169 156 138 129 134 136 114 101 99 100 99 99 98 103 108 119 128 131 160 171 140 126 113 106 112 108 82 64 60 39 116 184 173 179 171 165 161 182 199 198 170 149 170 170 174 185 173 148 132 123 122 126 120 106 109 124 129 124 97 64 61 58 78 112 130 136 165 177 143 121 106 104 124 107 75 63 60 40 86 181 175 176 175 169 162 175 203 203 179 164 179 175 172 143 109 97 84 106 158 175 184 171 164 168 134 76 43 33 65 86 90 105 122 142 174 175 134 116 98 119 135 99 70 60 59 48 69 169 183 173 174 170 164 169 197 209 190 164 179 170 142 130 126 79 44 55 82 127 142 124 112 105 72 54 71 89 111 102 88 96 120 149 180 163 127 110 100 136 126 84 60 57 60 50 59 146 190 174 173 174 168 167 189 204 199 175 164 150 145 168 171 143 111 125 135 144 135 133 139 136 129 128 128 126 112 85 78 102 128 155 174 141 127 100 119 144 114 73 58 60 62 50 50 118 189 181 173 175 171 167 180 196 194 181 166 162 161 163 151 155 164 168 166 164 155 155 155 148 141 135 124 105 85 78 90 122 138 156 149 140 124 98 140 138 94 64 60 63 64 47 48 80 170 191 177 174 180 172 169 187 189 177 170 172 172 169 159 148 142 141 140 139 137 139 133 125 116 106 96 86 81 88 113 122 127 135 142 155 102 119 154 118 76 62 68 65 65 39 46 52 130 185 185 174 182 178 170 174 186 178 171 176 187 178 164 151 135 121 115 118 121 116 110 104 99 93 92 92 93 111 127 125 137 138 161 126 94 144 139 96 70 69 71 61 74 35 40 44 84 166 188 183 176 180 178 174 179 185 180 193 193 180 171 160 150 151 154 152 151 146 141 135 119 108 101 96 102 128 137 145 144 133 126 91 118 147 117 82 74 78 72 61 101 38 36 44 53 127 181 187 178 174 181 180 173 183 190 190 196 195 178 164 161 167 172 168 165 171 163 154 141 128 115 104 117 149 155 139 124 111 96 99 139 135 102 88 86 82 72 64 140 43 37 41 43 75 161 181 183 173 174 179 180 175 190 199 197 198 189 181 173 166 171 173 180 176 158 148 141 126 115 113 129 147 136 132 115 97 91 125 148 124 105 94 87 77 66 82 181 44 41 35 41 45 114 177 177 181 177 175 183 184 176 192 198 184 186 195 198 188 173 174 172 167 157 145 138 121 121 115 113 125 146 133 98 83 111 148 145 122 107 90 85 75 58 118 203 48 44 35 36 42 58 144 181 189 188 182 182 187 181 172 180 189 192 193 198 192 186 178 165 160 152 138 128 128 129 110 111 139 132 105 83 97 143 153 137 118 97 87 79 68 68 168 211 45 45 41 32 38 40 90 163 179 190 184 186 185 189 182 176 185 194 199 187 175 173 162 156 156 145 128 125 127 121 104 111 121 110 89 87 131 153 148 130 106 85 77 71 60 107 199 208'

b = bytes(int(p) for p in pixels.split())
i = Image.frombuffer('L', (48, 48), b)
print(i)
i.save('example.png')
```

Outputs `example.png`:

[image]

Comment: Great!! Now I can proceed with my work.

Answer (score 0):

Yun can also use `numpy` to read the fixed-length data and save to image with `cv2`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

pixels = '126 126 129 120 110 168 174 172 173 174 170 157 134 97 78 75 118 119 97 117 142 86 58 71 124 161 162 134 100 119 124 118 153 135 143 180 180 172 153 128 98 67 60 75 85 89 85 98 123 126 131 119 119 172 180 171 155 127 100 82 77 72 54 97 184 151 157 176 125 74 71 114 173 171 136 109 116 118 118 150 152 150 178 191 188 187 180 169 152 127 86 60 74 91 92 95 119 131 127 115 113 153 130 94 71 62 65 69 83 95 79 137 181 174 196 148 88 75 103 149 135 107 100 105 104 112 140 162 178 191 187 181 171 166 159 156 159 155 144 97 54 69 83 91 112 116 100 85 74 73 59 58 67 75 74 80 104 110 96 153 180 182 151 100 103 139 167 172 152 141 135 135 141 163 182 191 191 183 179 169 144 127 132 147 156 154 152 143 92 52 56 78 97 86 69 60 51 48 55 65 74 74 71 92 121 122 115 155 177 166 151 158 181 200 201 208 207 198 187 181 182 189 187 187 179 170 154 119 91 86 101 124 139 154 153 153 132 73 51 60 63 52 48 45 46 54 65 78 79 86 96 131 163 146 133 162 179 193 202 211 205 208 216 218 209 204 191 183 184 183 176 170 153 127 96 98 127 148 148 142 134 140 150 154 149 102 49 53 57 58 65 68 70 75 75 74 90 121 151 176 176 148 156 170 193 209 215 211 203 213 219 212 206 201 183 174 173 166 162 135 101 86 99 147 176 175 166 164 157 146 148 155 154 128 55 53 54 54 77 92 89 68 58 61 69 94 143 171 155 150 161 163 185 197 203 202 207 213 212 209 202 195 176 163 157 153 125 83 86 118 160 179 172 165 161 161 166 164 155 155 153 138 74 54 40 70 110 122 106 92 112 123 116 108 96 94 118 146 155 159 166 174 180 187 198 213 216 205 196 192 178 155 139 117 88 96 131 163 159 142 130 126 123 123 132 139 147 156 158 145 75 59 60 117 163 157 138 157 176 179 186 189 167 121 98 105 123 149 161 162 165 178 196 213 214 199 188 181 171 147 117 97 104 124 134 127 123 131 135 139 138 137 144 146 139 147 135 106 75 69 98 155 184 180 178 189 187 182 181 190 203 198 165 126 102 109 138 162 171 193 216 225 222 204 191 182 154 130 116 118 137 143 125 108 100 96 96 102 122 129 145 158 142 96 90 127 88 50 125 175 195 191 191 189 178 166 165 172 175 178 177 162 139 116 112 130 158 194 211 216 218 202 189 165 132 129 134 143 129 104 86 98 80 90 128 97 70 90 117 149 161 109 127 151 112 58 145 187 200 198 192 185 174 171 180 162 135 117 120 126 128 128 124 116 124 157 171 166 156 126 107 92 101 127 129 104 93 105 119 137 113 136 145 136 118 107 119 149 162 147 152 152 125 77 142 183 189 176 177 178 174 163 118 109 118 109 95 83 94 101 114 134 125 120 152 153 154 152 156 124 99 103 122 111 112 136 151 156 163 160 160 163 155 143 145 159 163 137 141 147 126 86 119 158 161 184 183 185 163 100 98 167 135 126 89 99 116 104 101 146 144 115 162 197 201 191 189 156 112 94 103 108 112 127 141 150 153 155 156 148 141 149 156 157 165 155 144 146 129 86 112 140 156 191 190 179 144 126 159 179 160 150 148 143 135 127 135 138 137 117 151 199 195 178 177 169 123 105 100 106 115 132 138 143 145 145 143 139 149 156 156 151 141 141 143 143 130 94 131 136 142 181 198 188 177 189 193 185 183 166 152 136 123 121 130 125 132 143 186 207 192 177 177 169 140 119 128 141 142 147 154 159 158 155 158 156 153 146 132 114 122 136 136 134 127 105 136 143 151 167 184 190 198 189 175 168 160 148 138 131 131 144 160 181 176 168 212 206 202 198 185 173 160 150 133 139 148 155 158 164 165 158 146 133 119 113 118 127 130 127 126 125 124 113 176 181 163 183 177 177 184 186 183 172 164 160 160 164 165 174 189 184 171 206 218 212 206 198 187 180 177 171 157 125 113 116 121 127 126 126 126 129 133 136 134 128 121 118 117 115 113 111 175 199 166 177 196 190 188 189 190 190 188 186 184 182 183 189 179 150 171 208 219 209 201 191 181 173 167 152 150 159 157 148 149 154 155 157 153 146 142 140 130 124 117 112 113 108 100 104 175 199 190 163 181 191 187 187 191 191 189 185 179 170 161 155 150 168 168 185 221 204 193 181 168 165 157 137 120 126 158 167 164 168 168 166 160 152 147 144 138 127 118 113 106 103 95 95 173 196 200 206 189 175 168 169 171 167 166 159 154 155 162 176 190 172 147 191 213 202 193 179 162 158 154 137 124 108 123 155 163 167 169 167 164 157 151 144 135 128 120 113 106 99 92 89 164 192 203 215 214 208 206 193 183 175 173 176 179 185 194 196 182 142 148 202 213 204 202 187 173 165 154 151 135 112 102 131 154 157 162 161 158 149 142 137 129 123 117 108 101 95 88 85 156 189 205 211 206 206 206 202 197 198 194 197 201 201 195 178 156 129 171 211 216 214 208 190 179 171 168 149 132 117 102 112 134 152 154 150 150 143 137 131 123 119 112 103 96 91 83 84 148 189 202 204 201 198 199 201 202 201 197 194 192 191 177 159 133 136 189 206 208 210 199 186 180 176 161 129 129 117 106 114 126 144 149 149 145 141 135 130 122 116 108 98 93 90 81 83 149 190 200 199 194 196 199 194 193 192 185 182 180 172 161 141 129 159 188 186 193 194 185 176 173 164 123 93 105 104 117 127 125 132 145 149 142 137 134 129 119 111 103 96 92 87 79 83 159 190 197 198 190 188 188 186 182 180 174 169 165 160 145 126 134 180 187 154 158 186 175 154 151 137 99 84 87 101 124 130 131 131 140 146 143 136 133 126 117 109 99 92 88 85 76 80 171 189 192 187 184 182 182 179 173 169 168 160 156 148 135 124 158 191 196 172 158 169 146 126 123 117 103 102 104 114 128 132 135 133 133 143 144 138 130 122 112 104 96 90 87 84 76 73 175 190 184 180 178 173 171 169 167 162 159 156 152 139 123 131 177 189 192 188 177 167 147 122 111 101 100 110 116 117 131 133 133 135 134 140 144 138 129 117 108 103 97 95 92 85 76 69 179 191 186 178 171 168 164 162 156 151 153 150 144 131 118 151 181 191 198 193 183 175 163 136 112 109 115 118 121 126 136 132 130 132 129 137 144 140 127 116 108 105 101 99 92 86 76 67 160 190 184 173 169 161 156 152 148 144 146 147 141 120 126 172 184 195 203 200 191 184 174 159 142 139 133 129 133 138 135 131 124 124 127 130 141 145 132 119 112 109 106 104 96 88 73 64 110 184 188 176 168 158 145 143 144 147 146 146 136 115 145 176 184 198 199 196 197 190 178 163 159 157 149 145 144 141 134 129 121 119 126 128 138 151 141 124 117 113 110 106 98 88 69 60 89 172 189 178 170 163 149 138 144 152 155 154 128 128 166 178 184 193 197 200 198 192 182 170 163 168 162 156 147 140 136 132 121 115 118 124 130 155 152 132 126 118 110 106 98 86 66 56 60 157 186 180 173 167 153 142 155 167 166 156 125 151 174 178 178 185 193 189 191 188 175 168 167 162 144 130 126 122 122 124 118 112 117 121 124 155 163 137 129 118 110 107 104 86 63 57 41 140 184 178 178 170 159 154 172 183 181 158 134 161 170 176 176 184 184 169 156 138 129 134 136 114 101 99 100 99 99 98 103 108 119 128 131 160 171 140 126 113 106 112 108 82 64 60 39 116 184 173 179 171 165 161 182 199 198 170 149 170 170 174 185 173 148 132 123 122 126 120 106 109 124 129 124 97 64 61 58 78 112 130 136 165 177 143 121 106 104 124 107 75 63 60 40 86 181 175 176 175 169 162 175 203 203 179 164 179 175 172 143 109 97 84 106 158 175 184 171 164 168 134 76 43 33 65 86 90 105 122 142 174 175 134 116 98 119 135 99 70 60 59 48 69 169 183 173 174 170 164 169 197 209 190 164 179 170 142 130 126 79 44 55 82 127 142 124 112 105 72 54 71 89 111 102 88 96 120 149 180 163 127 110 100 136 126 84 60 57 60 50 59 146 190 174 173 174 168 167 189 204 199 175 164 150 145 168 171 143 111 125 135 144 135 133 139 136 129 128 128 126 112 85 78 102 128 155 174 141 127 100 119 144 114 73 58 60 62 50 50 118 189 181 173 175 171 167 180 196 194 181 166 162 161 163 151 155 164 168 166 164 155 155 155 148 141 135 124 105 85 78 90 122 138 156 149 140 124 98 140 138 94 64 60 63 64 47 48 80 170 191 177 174 180 172 169 187 189 177 170 172 172 169 159 148 142 141 140 139 137 139 133 125 116 106 96 86 81 88 113 122 127 135 142 155 102 119 154 118 76 62 68 65 65 39 46 52 130 185 185 174 182 178 170 174 186 178 171 176 187 178 164 151 135 121 115 118 121 116 110 104 99 93 92 92 93 111 127 125 137 138 161 126 94 144 139 96 70 69 71 61 74 35 40 44 84 166 188 183 176 180 178 174 179 185 180 193 193 180 171 160 150 151 154 152 151 146 141 135 119 108 101 96 102 128 137 145 144 133 126 91 118 147 117 82 74 78 72 61 101 38 36 44 53 127 181 187 178 174 181 180 173 183 190 190 196 195 178 164 161 167 172 168 165 171 163 154 141 128 115 104 117 149 155 139 124 111 96 99 139 135 102 88 86 82 72 64 140 43 37 41 43 75 161 181 183 173 174 179 180 175 190 199 197 198 189 181 173 166 171 173 180 176 158 148 141 126 115 113 129 147 136 132 115 97 91 125 148 124 105 94 87 77 66 82 181 44 41 35 41 45 114 177 177 181 177 175 183 184 176 192 198 184 186 195 198 188 173 174 172 167 157 145 138 121 121 115 113 125 146 133 98 83 111 148 145 122 107 90 85 75 58 118 203 48 44 35 36 42 58 144 181 189 188 182 182 187 181 172 180 189 192 193 198 192 186 178 165 160 152 138 128 128 129 110 111 139 132 105 83 97 143 153 137 118 97 87 79 68 68 168 211 45 45 41 32 38 40 90 163 179 190 184 186 185 189 182 176 185 194 199 187 175 173 162 156 156 145 128 125 127 121 104 111 121 110 89 87 131 153 148 130 106 85 77 71 60 107 199 208'

a = list(map(int, pixels.split(' ')))[:48 * 48]
i = np.array(a).reshape((48, 48)).astype('uint8')

cv2.imwrite('a.png', i)
```

Outputs `a.png`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqpHw.png)